# Can't update the mongodb document on the fly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am quite new to Node.js and MongoDB. I am trying to have this code in which I have a boolean document called test which is initially "false" in Mongodb and I want to alert that when a page /hello is loaded. then go to another page submit a form and update test to true and load /hello again. so this time it should alert true (when I check the database it has been updated to true) but it doesn't alert anything when I test it. Would be great if you let me know when am doing wrong!

here are the relevant codes in my app.js

```
app.post("/Submitted", function(req,res){ 
    var conditions = mongoose.model('users').findOne({username: req.session.user.username}, function (err, doc){
      doc.test = true;
      doc.save();
        res.redirect('hello');
    });


app.get('/hello', function (req, res) {
    var umbrella = req.session.user.test;
    if (req.session.user) {
        res.render('5points', {test: test});
    } else {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});
```

and here is my jade file:

```
script.
  function check() {
    var test= !{JSON.stringify(test)};
    alert(test);
body(onload= "check()")
```

Answer (score 0):

The res.redirect('hello') is getting triggered before the doc.save gets completed.Remember node.js is non blocking I/O.So you need to call the res.redirect inside the **callback of save.**

```
app.post("/Submitted", function(req, res) {
    var conditions = mongoose.model('users').findOne({
            username: req.session.user.username
        }, function(err, doc) {
            doc.test = true;
            doc.save(function(err) {
                if (err) return res.json(message: "error");
                res.redirect('hello');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi THanks for your response. I tried this. now it alerts it but it alerts false instead of true although it has updated it in the database.

Comment: Can it actually be that the session is not updated?! cause if the user sign in again it works fine! is there anyway to update the session?!